# Why is scan.nextFloat() not reading only float values?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I trying to read ONLY float value from a file that consists of integer and float values however when I do scan.nextFloat() it still reads the next integer value and converts it into floats and adds it to my list of points. Below is what I am doing.

```
while(scan.hasNextFloat()) {
     points.add(scan.nextFloat());
}
```

Sample points in a file

3 4

3.3 4 5

2.3 3 3

Is there a way to just read the float values from the file such as 3.3 and 2.3. Also shouldn't scan.nextFloat() read only float values while skipping the int values?

Comment: _"shouldn't scan.nextFloat() read only float values while skipping the int values"_ -- a Scanner skips only when explicitly told to, it doesn't magically decide what you meant to skip.  Also, a number without a decimal point is a valid float. If you want to ignore the integers you'll have to code explicitly to ignore them.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have to accept that `nextFloat` is going to read a number like 3 as 3.0. If you don't want numbers that are whole integers, then just filter them out after you've read them. (See the other answers.) But if you want to include "3.0" but not "3" then you will have to read the values in as strings and only parse the ones that have decimals:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
   String s = scan.next();
   if (s.indexOf('.') != -1) {
       double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
       // do something with d...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextFloat()) the `hasNextFloat()` method:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a float value using the nextFloat() method

[nextFloat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat()) states that (emphasis mine):

> (...)
>   If the next token matches the **Float** regular expression defined above then the token is converted into a float value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Float.parseFloat. If the token matches the localized NaN or infinity strings, then either "Nan" or "Infinity" is passed to Float.parseFloat as appropriate.

Float, on the other hand could be a Decimal, HexFloat or SignedNonNumber. Decimal could be a DecimalNumeral, which could be a Numeral, which is a Digit.

That's why.

Another way of taking only the float values is this (if your file contains only integers and floats of course):

```
while(scan.hasNext() && !scan.hasNextInt()) {
 points.add(scan.nextFloat());
```

}